# How to implement Authorization for Admin Application in react

Tags: reactjs, jhipster, google-authentication

I know normally I have to ask questions about specific code problems. But I need advice to get started at all. I was thinking about making a webapplication with react the application is a admin controll pannel things like, employee costs, orders and so on for a family business. For the authentication part I wanted to keep it simple and do it with google but before doing that, I wanted to ask the experienced developers here if that makes any sense or if I should use Jhipster/Keycloak.

Benefits of google would be I think it is easier to implement and the security part would be handled by google but what could be possible problems? I hope someone could give me a good advice.

with regards

Answer (score 0):

Using Keycloak/JHipster would probably be overkill for a simple family business application.

I would rather use simpler authentication types offered by JHipster that do not require external applications like session. An alternative would be to use provided Okta integration, this way you get a ready-to-go solution.

If you want to use Google, then you'll have to use spring-security-oauth2-client and build your own solution on top of Spring Boot or adapt JHipster generated app if you still want to use JHipster.

Also, do you have decided of where you want to deploy your app? Your cloud provider could offer a good integrated solution for authentication.